# systemd service using 100% of my CPU when it doesn't if I start it without systemd

Tags: debian, systemd

I'm using Debian Jessie with the latest updates. I made a systemd service to run a script when my server starts. Here's its configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description=(my description)

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bot
Restart=restart-always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`/usr/bin/bot` is a script running a Mono executable. It consists of:

```
#!/bin/bash
(cd /path/to/my/executable && mono bot.exe)
```

(I replaced the path here, but the one on my script is correct.)

When I run the script `/usr/bin/bot` normally (simply `/usr/bin/bot` on my terminal), it is working as expected. `top` reports it's using between 0 and, say, 20% of my CPU, which is normal. But when I start it with `service bot start`, `top` says it's always using at least 100% of my CPU.

In both cases `bot` is working as expected.

What could explain such a big difference in CPU usage?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried this on any other systemd based systems?  Jessie isn't a stable release yet.  Might be good to bring this to their attention.

Comment: I'll install Wheezy and try.

Comment: Wheezy only included a tech preview of systemd.  So I don't know if it will be any different.  systemd is new to the Debian and Ubuntu scene.  Here is a list of distributions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd#Adoption_and_reception

Comment: Oh, right. Well, I don't actually *need* to use systemd, I only started using it because after upgrading to Jessie (I believe), my inittab wasn't taken into account anymore, probably because it was using systemd instead. Though there are other scripts that Debian runs with systemd, and those don't use 100% CPU. But I'd rather not go back to SysV since systemd is probably going to be widespread in the future.

Comment: It could be an issue with systemd, but like I said, Jessie isn't a stable release, so I wouldn't rule out it being an issue with Jessie's implementation.  The only way to know for certain is to test your service on a stable systemd system like Fedora, Arch, SuSE, RHEL7, etc.

Comment: I'll try one of these then.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense for this to be a systemd bug if it is literally the `bot` process which is using all the CPU.  Systemd is not magical and can't affect your program's behavior beyond starting it, sending it signals, and perhaps killing it.

Comment: As goldilocks said, the program behaviour is key here. But since you haven't even given us the output of `systemctl status bot.service` (run as the superuser) we have nothing to tell us _what that behaviour is_.  For all we know, your program isn't suitable for running when it lacks a controlling terminal.

Comment: That wrapper script to just change directory is completely unnecessary when one is using a systemd service unit, by the way, and is an extra (script interpreter) process for no good reason.  And for all we know (because you aren't telling us the reality of your system, but bowdlerizing things), that wrapper could equally be the cause of the problem because you have a readiness protocol mismatch between a `forking` service and a `simple` service unit description.

Comment: And if you had even only given people the `/etc/inittab` record that your system used to use, someone could have shown you what a systemd service unit equivalent for it would be.

Answer (score 4):

Problem is not located in systemd.

Systemd runs process without stdin (=/dev/null). All syscalls to `read()` are finished immediately (with normal stdin, `read()` is blocked until new data arrive). In general practice `read()` is called within unfinished loop making huge CPU usage. 
To confirm this, try to attach to running process with `strace -p <pid>`.

Process has to be adapted to run without stdin or use some wrappers like proposed `screen` command or `nohup`

Comment: +1 for the info about the root cause. But you could elaborate your resolution.

Answer (score 3):

I "fixed it" by putting my `bot` under a `screen`, like so:

```
[Unit]
Description=(my description)

[Service]
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -dmS bot /usr/bin/bot
Restart=restart-always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I don't know why putting my process in a screen fixes its high CPU usage, but hey, it works.

Comment: I was having the same issue, and this worked. However, I used -D instead of -d so that the screen would stay attached and systemd could continue to track the service after it started.

Comment: This is a workaround for a real solution. Either configure your service to have a standard input, or avoid reading from standard input in your code.

Answer (score 1):

As per @niziak's solution the input is blocking. In my case solved by 
Adding `StandardInput=tty` to the [Service] fixed it. I was already re-directing output to an (unused) console on /dev/tty12.

My [service] section:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/vtclock -1  -c| -f /tmp/ntpstatus
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=255
Type=simple
User=vtclock
StandardInput=tty
StandardOutput=tty
StandardError=null
TTYPath=/dev/tty12
```

(OS = Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, my first attempt at a systemd service)

Answer (score 1):

I see this is an old thread, but I leave my scenario here, maybe a few years time some finds it usefull.

I have a discord bot in c# dotnet core.

I made a systemctl daemon for it in my ubuntu server.

I have the git repo stored on te server as well. when I used it in test, I went with the

```
dotnet run
```

it consumed 0,3% of cpu.

I made a publish of it and placed it in my active server folder.
From there in the daemon it went to 100% cpu usage in the daemon.

I got mixed between the differrent versions, but I felt that it was runing normally from terminal.

but no.

My rookie mistake was doing

```
dotnet publish -r linux-x64 --self-contained true
```

instead of

```
dotnet publish -r linux-x64
```

But for a long time I did not noticed, because the self contained version was runing fine with minimal cpu, until I moved out from the procet bin directory.

Comment: This answer is missing a root cause information. Why would a self-contained build use 100% CPU? Is this a bug in the runtime?

Answer (score 0):

If you've developed a console application in C# / .NET Core, don't use this to keep the console running:

```
Console.Read();
```

As it will result in 100% CPU usage when you run the application as a systemd service on linux.

Rather use:

```
while (true) { Console.ReadKey(); }
```

I had the same problem.

Comment: Thanks. You can also have a command-line argument to start your application in a way that would avoid calling Console methods.