# Ubuntu systemd using 100% CPU when running manually with sudo only uses 20%

Tags: debian, ubuntu, systemd, golang

I wrote a program in Golang (it is compiled) and ran it using systemd as it needs to run long-term, auto reboot and run on startup, but it's pinning the cpu at 100%. Comparatively when running using sudo through the terminal, it only uses about 20%. The program is very I/O intensive if that helps.

I was also reading [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191621/systemd-service-using-100-of-my-cpu-when-it-doesnt-if-i-start-it-without-syste/692075#692075) which seems to have a similar issue and I tried running it behind a screen and nohup with systemd and still had the same problem. Also tried adding tty for I/O but that didn't seem to work either.

Any help to get this to work or alternatives to systemd would be greatly appreciated.

```
[Unit]
Description=Program Description
Documentation=N/A
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment=PORT=54731
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/GoProxy/proxy
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Edit:
My program is a custom proxy solution I wrote. The intensive I/O is from having to read files for authentication checking and logging runtime info to a log file.

Edit:
I've used daemon with sudo (root perms) to run it with restart on crash and so far that's working fine. But I then tried to automatically start it with daemon when the server boots using cron and it has the same problem when doing this (I used cron through sudo, so should run as root)

Comment: Does it also do a lot of logging to stdout/stderr? I can see how piping lots and lots of data into the system journaling mechanisms might make a difference (compared to a terminal window that only cares about 1000 lines of scrollback or so).

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz No, it has a small stdout at the start to show startup details but besides that it logs to a file using Golang's log.Println

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Forgot to mention but it also does a lot of reading from JSON files for various functions.

Comment: well, this sounds like a bug in your program. You can figure out what it does with that 100% CPU, eg. using `perf top`. Also note that using 100% CPU might not be a bad thing – if running it as root allows it to bypass IO limitations, then you might stop being IO-limited and start being CPU-limited. I don't know what your program does!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I don't think that's the case. When it gets to 100% utilization it has problems doing I/O proccesses which then causes runtime errors. But when run manually (with root perms) it has no issues and only uses 20% cpu. And I'll add an edit describving my program

Comment: as said, actually go and figure out what it *does* when it uses the 100% CPU. It certainly sounds like a bug.